# max parameter is not working in restdb.io

Tags: json, database, api, nosql, restdb

I have a db on restdb.io from which I only want to get data of last 7 days for which I tried using max but it isn't working probably because I'm grouping the data using date field and sorting the data according to the date field so that I would get the data in descending order

Any help would be great, even some work arounds would be okay.

url : https://oidata-5bdd.restdb.io/rest/oidata?groupby=Date&dir=-1&sort=Date

Comment: Please provide minimum reproducible code and/or what you have tried so far in your question.

Comment: I'm new to the restdb and I haven't try any thing else than the max parameter, im using this url to fetch data in js using ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using aggregation operators max and skip params are ignored.
I think a workaround could be to create a custom route with a query and e.g. map/reduce to get the result you want.

https://restdb.io/docs/custom-rest-routes#restdb